# consuming jasperIntelligence services with nusoap(PHP)

Tags: php, jasper-reports, axis, nusoap

i've been struggling the whole week end to connect to jasperIntelligence service in vain with a php client.Of course there is a sample php client in the jasperserver installation and that seems to be very very old.  I've decided to write my own using the latest nusoap 0.7.3.It seems like i'm not getting well the structure of the webservice.
In the webservice guide pdf the request should look like this

```
<request operationName="runReport" locale="en">
  <argument name="RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT">JRPRINT</argument>
  <resourceDescriptor name="" wsType="" uriString="/reports/samples/EmployeeAccounts" isNew="false">
  <label>null</label>
  <parameter name="EmployeeID">emil_id</parameter>
  <parameter name="TEST_LIST" isListItem="true">A &amp; L Powers Engineering, Inc</parameter>
  <parameter name="TEST_LIST" isListItem="true">A &amp; U Jaramillo Telecom, Inc</parameter>
  <parameter name="TEST_LIST" isListItem="true">A &amp; U Stalker Telecom, Inc</parameter>
  </resourceDescriptor>
</request>
```

Honestly i'm not getting the `argument tag` part therefore don't know how to pass it through nusoap.
Also don't know how to pass the `uriString` which defines the address of the report to run actually.uri keyword is used as namespace in most of things i've seen so far.
Those cannot be taken as parameters.I'm really confused.

I'm tempted to use an xml made up with argument tag and attributes and post it as headers but at the same time i think it's wrong.

I can connect with nusaop, call the getOperationData but can make request.What do you suggest? Can anyone share it's experience? Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it.has to be Pear SOAP to consume jasper webservices